# VB.NET database is not in MS Access and login error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I use Microsoft Access to store the data. The register form shows msgbox that the data was saved but there isn't any data stored in the table when I check the table on Microsoft Access. Is it supposed to be like that or did I code wrong?

This is my register code

```
If PasswordTextBox.Text.Length >= 8 Then
                Try
                    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database2.accdb")
                    Dim insert As String = "Insert into Table1 values('" & NameTextBox.Text & "','" & Staff_IDTextBox.Text & "','" & Phone_NoTextBox.Text & "','" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "','" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "');"
                    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insert, conn)
                    conn.Open()
                    'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Saved")
                    For Each txt As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                        txt.Text = ""
                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Error")
                End Try
            Else
                MsgBox("Password must be more than 8 character")
            End If
        End If
```

This is my login code

```
uname = UsernameTextBox.Text
            pword = PasswordTextBox.Text
            Dim query As String = "Select password From Table1 where name= '" & uname & "';"
            Dim dbsource As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database2.accdb"
            Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Try
                pass = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Username does not exit")
            End Try
            If (pword = pass) Then
                MsgBox("Login succeed")
            Else
                MsgBox("Login failed")
                UsernameTextBox.Clear()
                PasswordTextBox.Clear()
            End If
```

There is an error at this line
`pass = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString`

It says:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery" is commented out, so the code will not save anything to the database.
2. You should close your connection after executing the INSERT command.
3. By default the table will have auto-numbered field as the first item in the table.  You will need to remove this field from your table for that specific INSERT command to work.

Or you may need to use a slightly different INSERT command.  It is useful to have auto-numbered ID fields in a table.

4. You probably should catch the exception and display ex.Message in your message box rather then "Error".  The ex.Message will be much more helpful to you in debugging your program.

I have made all of these mistakes in my code at one time or other.

Answer (score 1):

Your Login Code;

1)
You should catch the exception message and display in it a message box.  This will make debugging faster.

The actual exception in your code will read "{"No value given for one or more required parameters."}

Your query is incorrect.

2. You should do the open, query, and close of the connection inside the Try-Catch block.  Test for a null password afterwards to determine if the username does not exist.

Two separate answers provided, because you have two very separate questions.

Best wishes...